# Unable to load profile Accounts :AWS toolkit for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin

I am unable to load my credential file with eclipse after i have copy pasted my access id and secret key. It says the format of the credential file is incorrect whereas i have made no  changes to format  except pasted my details.

[image]

My Credential file looks like this.

[image]

**Solution :** 
I deleted the credentials file and restarted eclipse. It created a new credentials file in which i filled the credentials again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you add your profile name to the credentials?

`[Profile name]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`